# First Item in dropdownlist doesn't fire SelectedIndexChanged at all

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have following simple code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="testForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="Orbs.testForm" %>
<html>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="dropdown1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropdown1_SelectedIndexChanged" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
            <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Item 1" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Item 2" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Item 3" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="Item 4" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="Item 5" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="label1"></asp:Label>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my code behind

```
using System;

namespace Orbs {
    public partial class testForm: System.Web.UI.Page {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            label1.Text = "???!!";
        }

        protected void dropdown1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            label1.Text = "Fired on " + dropdown1.SelectedValue;
        }

    }
}
```

When the first time I enter the page, `label1` shows `'???!!'`. Now I select an item from dropdown and `label1` shows correct value but when I select first item in dropdown, it again shows `???!!` instead of `Fired on 1`

Where I'm doing wrong?

Edit: I noticed if I add `Selected="True"` to any of the items in the dropdown, that item becomes victim and won't fire the event!

Comment: Ohhh, sorry can you see the break point on the event?

Comment: No, it is not firing when I'm selecting first item. Selecting rest of the items will fire it

Comment: well i don't think the index has changed when you are selecting the first item, since its actually the same index at which its loaded

Comment: @V4Vendetta: I'm selecting different value before selecting first one and page refreshes too, meaning there is no problem from client side and it is from something in server side that is not working.

Comment: Seems to work properly at my end, are you doing anything else or least can you try it with a clean build

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem myself,

I read somewhere that turning off the `ViewStateMode` will cause `DropDownList`not work properly. In my web application I had to turn off `ViewStateMode` to achieve some global task and turn it on case by case.

Somehow turning on `ViewStateMode` on `DropDownList` is not working, I even tried turning on `ViewStateMode` for page and master page but still `DropDownList` didn't work. it only worked when I turned on `ViewStateMode` in `web.config`.

As turning on `ViewStateMode` in `web.config` is not an option, I found and alternate solution. I'm including it here hoping it help someone.

- Add a `HiddenField` to your form.
- In `Page_Load` compare value of `HiddenField` with `Request.Forms[DropDownList1.UniqueID]`
- if they are different, call `SelectedIndexChanged` manually
- Set the value of `HiddenField` to value of `Request.Forms[DropDownList1.UniqueID]`.

Comment: Just to follow up on this. I put ViewStateMode=Enabled on the dropdown control and that solved the problem. Perhaps something has changed between now and then.

Comment: If you check my sample code, `ViewStateMode=Enabled` is already there but I disabled it in `web.config` and it wasn't working

Comment: Putting the ViewStateMode=Enabled on the dropdown control worked for me too.

Comment: EnableViewState="true" did not work for me on the control but it did work for the page. I'm using ASP.NET 4.5.2. ViewStateMode="Enabled" as noted above did not work either. Why are there two options that sound the same?

Comment: from MSDN document `The ViewStateMode property of a page or a control has an effect only if the EnableViewState`. Sometimes it is desirable to turn off page viewstate to reduce size of cached data inside page

Answer (score 18):

For Anyone still having the problem; I solved it in a different, yet easier way:
Just add a dummy ListItem to the start of the DropDownList and set that item's Enabled property to false.
i.e.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dropdown1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropdown1_SelectedIndexChanged" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
        <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="" Enabled="false" />
        <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Item 1" />
        <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Item 2" />
        <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Item 3" />
        <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="Item 4" />
        <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="Item 5" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Does it behave like this because the first item is usually not an actual option?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue - SelectedIndexChanged doesn't fire when selecting the first option,
My not clean solution was (not sure that was so smart but it work for me),

At the Page_Load I added the follow script:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            //bind data first time
        }
        else
        {
            int ddlSortByValue = int.Parse(ddlSortBy.SelectedValue);
            if (ddlSortByValue == 0)
            {
                ddlSortBy_SelectedIndexChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }

        }
```

That way I force the SelectedIndexChanged event to fire up

Comment: Your Solution working only if your first item in dropdown is the selected item (if another item from list is selected it won't work) and your values should be numbers (it won't work if your values are string)

Answer (score 1):

This question covers all the possibilities better than other posts out there, so I'm adding this explicit answer. In my case @Edyn's comment worked, even though the original problem already has this:

Set `ViewStateMode="Enabled"` on the dropdown control itself.
I also set it on the page declaration at the top of the page, just in case.

This is .Net 4.0, so perhaps something was changed (but certainly not fixed nicely).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but I solved it by calling `onindexchanged` function manually, like this:

```
ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(null, null);
```

I know this may not be the perfect way but it's working for me.

Comment: if you call SelectedIndexChanged manually your method will run twice if user selects items other than first one.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are setting the label to "???!!" every page event.

You need to modify your page load to detect f a Postback has not occured.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            label1.Text = "???!!";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I already had exact same answer from someone else who deleted his comment. if I remove the line from `Page_Load`, still the `dropdown1_SelectedIndexChanged` event won't fire and label remains empty

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this happened because I had referred to that dropdown using a local dropdownlist variable, and disposed off that variable at the end of a function. I was adding the first item to the dropdownlist after setting a datasource. Took me 2 hours to find this, and worked perfectly after I removed the dispose call.