# OnSelectedIndexChanged event won't fire for the first element of DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a `DropDownList` and the method for `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event changes the content of one label. It works fine except for the first element of the `DropDownList`. Any ideas?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Newsletter.DAL;
using Newsletter.Services;

public partial class Senders : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private SenderService _client;
    private List<Sender> _allSenders;
    private DropDownList _dropDownListSenders;
    private TextBox _emailBox;
    private string _selectedSender;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _client = new SenderService();
        _allSenders = _client.GetAllSenders();
        _dropDownListSenders = (DropDownList)loginViewMain.FindControl("DropDownListSenders");
        _emailBox = (TextBox)loginViewMain.FindControl("textBoxEmail");
    }

 protected void DropDownListSenders_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _selectedSender = _dropDownListSenders.SelectedValue;
        _emailBox.Text = _selectedSender;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try setting `AutoPostback` to true on the DDL.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699163/first-item-in-dropdownlist-doesnt-fire-selectedindexchanged-at-all

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an 'empty' item before the first item? If not, then selecting the first item will not change the selected index (the first item was already selected) and the event will not fire.

Answer (score 1):

I added `ViewStateMode="true"` to the `DropDownList` and now it works fine.

Comment: ViewStateMode="Enabled" should be there, not "true"

Answer (score 0):

Your 1st element is already selected that's why when you select the 1st element again its `OnSelectedIndexChanged` wont fire because you are not changing the element. 

`OnSelectedIndexChanged` will only fire if your selected element is changed.

Comment: and what should we do with that ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your first item if it is set to Empty string (i.e. **string.Empty**). If so, then set it to **null**. This should resolve your problem.

**Issue with Empty string** : - Event does not consider changing empty string to something new as changed. whereas if you set it to null, it says null has been changed to string value. 
Hope this helps! Happy coding...